# scss variables are not working in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Before the latest angular rc release my ionic 2 app worked perfectly fine.

After the latest release I noticed the styles were not all rendering properly. After further inspection I found that the scss variables were not rendering. 
I know I can go through all the styles and replace the variables with the color values but I'd like to keep the simplicity of the variables incase there ever needs to be a color change.

I can not seem to find how to get these variables working again, has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Please check if your build tool is compiling it properly.

Comment: @user32 it is compiling everything else in the style sheet, except the variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with current RC3 version of Ionic.
- Debugging in chrome does not work with TS
- The SCSS issue reported here.
I found out I can only fix one or the other.

To avoid SCSS problem make sure you remove in package.json

```
"config": {
  "ionic_bundler": "rollup",  
  "ionic_source_map": "source_map"  
},
```

and in tsconfig.json compile options

```
"sourceMap": true
```

=> Consequence, you can not use chrome for debugging TS. But you can use the cordova debugger in VSCode with TS.

Add again in Package.json and tsconfig.json the config values
and chrome debugger works again, but you will have the SCSS problem.

I guess it has something to do with the bundling of the asset files, done with webpack by default since RC?.

- Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.44
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Windows 7
- Node Version: v6.9.1
- Xcode version: Not installed